# How to disable word-wrap in Xcode 4 editor?

Tags: editor, word-wrap, xcode4

I can't find how to disable word-wrap in Xcode 4 editor. How can I do it?

Comment: Because SO recommends up voting to questions too when you find useful information.

Comment: Because it is so not obvious I still need the answer of this question, 2 years after it has been asked.

Comment: The question is useful because the UI is not intuitive

Comment: I sometimes wonder how long Apple guys will keep it. Now we're on Xcode 5 era.

Comment: Xcode 6 - still the same. Thanks for the question (and answer below of cource)

Comment: Come on. Word wrap in a code editor by default? Seems apple is so "perfect" that they think editing code is the same as a document file.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

Go to `Xcode Preferences -> Text Editing -> Indentation` and deselect `Line wrapping`.

Comment: In the file inspector, in the utilities panel (one on the right), theres a check box to enable/disable this for each file individually.

Comment: Haha, I “always” thought that it was impossible to turn line wrapping in Xcode. Then I come to this answer, and I see I’ve already upvoted it in the past. -_-

Answer (score 28):

David Hancock has it right (`Xcode Preferences -> Text Editing -> Indentation` and deselect `Line wrapping`), but just to add on -- even after reading that, I had trouble finding the option. I see now that `Editing` and `Indentation` are at the top of the box, but they are only written in clickable text (at least in Xcode 5)... I was expecting more of a conventional tab UI and had skipped right over them the first couple of times I looked.

[image]

Just a heads-up for anyone like me who might have accidentally skipped over them too...

Comment: Took me a moment too to realize it was more of a tab up top for indentation than an area in the main text editing option section.

Comment: See comments in David Hancook's answer above for doing this per file.

Answer (score 4):

For those who couldn't find the line wrap setting, it has been moved to the `Display` tab:

[image: Xcode -> Preferences... -> Text Editing -> Display -> Line Wrapping]

Xcode -> Preferences... -> Text Editing -> Display -> Line Wrapping